# javascript "header" file to store some data

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays

I have a big array that stores probably a few thousand of objects. I will need this array in my javascript file, but I don't want to have the array part inside the javascript. Instead, does js support header file, like a .h file in C++, so I can define the array in that header file and just include it in the main js file? Thank you!

Comment: You can write a json file and just make a `$.get` to retrieve that data.

Comment: Awww, got you, thank you so much!

Comment: Javascript doesn't have this built-in, but there are libraries like `require.js` that can be used to manage code spread over multiple files. Also, the server may have server-side include mechanisms (I've seen this done in HTML, not sure if it works for JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var showData;

    $.getJSON('example.json', function (data) {
       showData = data;
    });

});
```

Comment: Of course, this solution requires JQuery, so you would need to import that library as well.

Comment: @Scott Marcus You can go through xmlhttpRequest in javascript if you don't need to use jquery library. That also works as well.

Comment: I know that, but your answer doesn't show this, so that's why I left the additional comment.